# LINQPad: Changing SQL Server Password

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I personally prefer LINQPad to SQL Studio and there is one scenario where I'm still having to open SQL Studio to perform a task and that is changing a password for my logins when it has expired. LINQPad reflects a failed login and doesn't show that the password expired in the connection list. It DOES tell you it has expired if you open the connection properties and run a connection test.

Still it doesn't provide a way to change the password. Is there some way to accomplish password changes when they expire in LINQPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [latest beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) - LINQPad now detects password expiry in SQL Server and displays a password change dialog.

Let me know how you get along!

Comment: LINQPad just keeps getting better and better. Thank you!